# Some issue understanding the proof that a limit is unique

Tags: limits, proof-verification

We want to show that, if $lim(s_n) = s$ and $lim(s_n) = t$, then $s = t$.

---

The definition of limit $a$ for a sequence $s_n$ is:

> For each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$, such that $\forall n > N$, then we have that $\left|s_n - a \right| < \epsilon$.

---

I am not fully understanding (because of some details) the explanation in my book that a limit is unique:

> Consider $\epsilon > 0$. By definition of limit, there must exists $N_1$, so that: $$n > N_1 \text{  implies  } \left|s_n - s \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$
>
> and there must exist $N_2$, so that: $$n > N_2 \text{  implies  } \left|s_n - t \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$
>
> For $n > max\{N_1, N_2\}$, the triangle inequality shows that:
>
> $$\left|s - t \right| = \left|(s - s_n) + (s_n - t)\right| \leq \left|s - s_n\right| + \left|s_n - t\right| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$
>
> This shows that $\left|s - t \right| < \epsilon$, for all $\epsilon > 0$. It follows that $\left|s - t \right| = 0$, hence $s = t$.

---

There are **3 things** I don't understand.

1. Why $< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (and not simply $< \epsilon$) in the definitions for the limits $s$ and $t$?
2. How exactly did he obtain this: $\left|s - t \right| = \left|(s - s_n) + (s_n - t)\right|$? More precisely, why did he exchange $(s_n - s)$ with $(s - s_n)$?
3. Where does this conclusion $\left|s - t \right| = 0$ come from?

Answer (score 2):

1. This is valid because the statement 'there exists some $N$ such that $|s-s_n| < \alpha$ for all $n\ge N$' is true for any positive value $\alpha > 0$, including $\alpha = \epsilon/2$.  Note that for the sake of the proof $\epsilon/2$ is chosen twice because the author foresees that this will be convenient because of the triangle inequality argument.
2. The intuition is that $s_n$ is close to both $t$ and $s$ due to the limit statements, which in turn means that $t$ and $s$ are close to one another.  Note that $a-b = a-c+c-b$ for all $a,b,c$ since the $c$'s cancel.  This lets us write $s-t = s-s_n+s_n-t$, and then we take the absolute value.  Note that $|-x| = |x|\;$, so we can rewrite $|s-s_n| = |s_n-s| < \epsilon/2$.
3. The general statement is that if $x$ satisfies $|x|<\epsilon$ for all positive $\epsilon$, then $x=0$.  Otherwise $|x|$ would be positive, and setting $\epsilon = |x|$ would lead to the contradiction $|x| < |x|$.

Comment: We want to subtract the two limits since $|s-t|$ represents the distance between them.  If $s \ne t$, then this distance is some nonzero quantity.  However, by choosing large $n$ we can force $s_n$ to be close to $s$ and $t$ simultaneously.  This is impossible if we in particular force $s$ to be within $|s-t|/2$ of both $s$ and $t$.

Comment: We can   alternatively see that point 3 is saying that the intersection of the open intervals $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ is the one-point set $\{0\}$.  Consider a set of smaller and smaller intervals around zero, and maybe this will make sense.